# Keyboard stop working after GRUB

Tags: installation, server, keyboard

My keyboard works fine in bios, it even works when I enter GRUB which unetbootin created. After I select Install, and I'm presented with language options for installation, keyboard stops working. Every in installation results in LED blink on keyboard, nothing else.

I have to mention I'm installing Ubuntu server 13.10 64bit. My computer don't have PS2 slot so I can't try it with ps2 keyboard. I also tried another keyboard -> same result.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your machine and enter into your BIOS and Enable legacy USB support, Restart and it will Works..

Comment: Already did this. No luck :(